# Web Scraping a website with javax.faces.viewstate

Tags: java, web-scraping, scrapy

How do I scrape a website with javax.faces.viewstate.

In each request `javax.faces.viewstate=<big integer>` is sent.

But these numbers are not present in the webpages.

Looks like some csrf equivalent in java.

If I need to automate some queries in a website that uses this javax.faces.viewstate, What's the way to go about.

Example website: https://www.irctc.co.in/
India's most used website!

Comment: Have you see headers and params ? try use develop mode from chrome or firefox..

Comment: When I had to deal with `javax.faces.viewstate` in requests I always could find the value in the page source. Maybe you can disclose the exact URL and add it to your question. Then the experts on this site can try if they find it.